# Decode JavaScript btoa() encoded string using Java/Kotlin Base64 decoder

Tags: javascript, java, kotlin, base64, decoding

I have an encoded string as follows:

```
S0VEQUkgUlVOQ0lUIFZSSU5FIEVOVEVSUFJJU0UgLSBLRyBTSU1QQU5HIDQgU09PSw
```

This was encoded using JavaScript `btoa()` function. This string can be correctly decoded using JavaScript `atob()` function. It should give the following decoded string :

```
KEDAI RUNCIT VRINE ENTERPRISE - KG SIMPANG 4 SOOK
```

Right now I'm developing Android app and I have to decode this string, I'm using the following to decode :

```
java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedstring).toString();
```

I'm not getting the correct decoded output. Anyone knows what's the problem ? Is it even possible to decode using Java ?

Answer (score 2):

`decode(String)` returns a `byte[]`, you need to convert that to a string using a `String` constructor and not the `toString()` method:

```java
byte[] bytes = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedstring);
String s = new String(bytes, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working! I'm using String constructor now. I'm still new with Java so I will check the difference between String constructor and toString method

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need mime decoder message

```js
java.util.Base64.Decoder decoder = java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder();  
// Decoding MIME encoded message  
String dStr = new String(decoder.decode(encodedstring));  
System.out.println("Decoded message: "+dStr);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I found the solution. I have to use String constructor instead of toString method